# Mathematica and WolframAlpha gives wrong result about DiracDelta function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematica-online

Wolfram alpha says the integral does not converge and also Mathematica didn't give answer to the integral:

$$\int_0^t\delta(z)\delta(t-z)dz$$

which should gives the result of $\delta(t)$ as you will get if you calculated it manually using Dirac delta properties.

$$\int_a^b\delta(z)f(z)dz = f(0)$$ given that 0 is in the domain of integral.

[image]

Comment: I don't think $\delta(t)$ is the correct result here.

Comment: `Integrate[DiracDelta[x - a] DiracDelta[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`gives `DiracDelta[a]`

Comment: After some more thought I think the correct answer could be $\int_0^t\delta(z)\delta(t-z)dz=0$. I'm not sure about the correctness of my math though.

Comment: The integral under consideration is not defined since the upper limit of the integration coincides with the support of  $\delta(t-z)$  over $z$. For example, see [that book for info.](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Theory_of_Distributions.html?id=_DLvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: The same issue with $\delta(z)$ and the lower limit of the integration.

Comment: I'd like to add that Piotr Antosik, Jan Mikusiński, Roman Sikorski in Theory of distributions. Sequential approach made an attempt to introduce the definite integrals of  distributions.  That attempt can hardly be called very successful.

Comment: @Roman The correct result seems to be a `DiracDelta[t] HeavisideTheta[t] ` which is cutoff by `HeavisideTheta[t]`. Something like one half of the `DiracDelta` -distribution.

Answer (score 4):

⚠️ sketchy math alert ⚠️

Similar to what @UlrichNeumann proposes, let's approximate the Dirac $\delta$-function by a Gaussian of standard deviation $\sigma$ and then take $\sigma\to0^+$:

```
δ[x_] = E^(-x^2/(2σ^2))/(σ*Sqrt[2π]);

f[σ_, t_] = Integrate[δ[z]*δ[t-z], {z, 0, t}]
(*    E^(-t^2/(4σ^2)) * Erf[t/(2σ)] / (2σ*Sqrt[π])    *)
```

$f_{\sigma}(t)$ is an odd function: $f_\sigma(-t)=-f_{\sigma}(t)$.
For small $\sigma>0$ this function looks kind of like the first derivative of the $\delta$-function:

```
Plot[f[0.1, t], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Let's calculate some integrals:

```
Assuming[σ > 0,
  Integrate[f[σ, t], {t, -∞, ∞}]]
(*    0    *)

Assuming[σ > 0,
  Integrate[f[σ, t] * t, {t, -∞, ∞}]]
(*    σ * Sqrt[2/π]    *)
```

Compare this to the integral

```
Integrate[-σ*Sqrt[2/π]*DiracDelta'[t] * t, {t, -∞, ∞}]
(*    σ * Sqrt[2/π]    *)
```

These results suggest that as $\sigma\to0^+$ we have $f_{\sigma}(t)\approx-\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\delta'(t)$. In the limit $\sigma\to0^+$ we therefore have $f(t)=\lim_{\sigma\to0^+}f_{\sigma}(t)=0$.

Comment: I find it rather plausible reasoning and  wishful thinking than mathematics.

Comment: @user64494 do you have anything constructive to add? Noise from the cheap seats is not useful for anyone here.

Comment: @Roman Nice and clear answer!

Comment: I think this has to be incorrect, since it will involve the two deltas having the same singular set. To show rigorously that it is wrong one might proceed by using a different approximation for one of the deltas. Instead of centering it at 0, center it at `t/n` and let `n->Infinity` for example. This might give a different result and, if it does, that means the original integral was not well defined. Also there is a problem with integrating to `z` to `t` when the singular point is at `z=t`; one needs to integrate past the singular point for the integral to be well defined.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I won’t be surprised in the least if my result is wrong. As I said, sketchy math. It’s far too easy to get this kind of question wrong because details of the definitions matter crucially and the usual physicist’s fudging (“A Dirac delta is just a sharp Gaussian”) may be off the mark here.

Comment: Since $\delta[z]$ is non-zero only at $z=0$ and $\delta[t-z]$ is non-zero only at $z=t$, for every real value of z at least one of them is zero, so it makes sense that the integral is zero.

Comment: @BillWatts yes that’s true for all $t\neq0$. The real question is what happens at $t=0$.

Comment: At $t=0$, your upper and lower integration limits are the same.  Why are you even considering that?

Comment: @BillWatts because the integrand is very infinite and so even an integral over an interval of size zero will give something, maybe. Remember that we're talking improper integrals over distributions here, not Riemann integrals over functions.

Comment: I doubt that an integral over a zero interval is meaningful, even with $\delta's$

Answer (score 2):

Using DiracDelta as a limit

```
dirac=Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] eps]]
```

we get

```
Integrate[dirac [t - x ] dirac [x] , {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {Element[{t, eps}, Reals], eps > 0}]
(*(E^(-(t^2/(4 eps))) Erf[t/(2 Sqrt[eps])])/(2 Sqrt[eps] Sqrt[\[Pi]])*)
```

Reinserting definition `dirac`  the expression might be transformed to

```
DiracDelta[t/Sqrt[2]]/Sqrt[2] Erf[t/(2 Sqrt[eps])]==DiracDelta[t]  Erf[t/(2 Sqrt[eps])]
```

Limit `eps->0` gives the final result

```
DiracDelta[t] (2 HeavisideTheta[t]-1)
```

Comment: I don’t think you define the Heaviside function right. What you need is rather $2\Theta(t)-1$, not just $\Theta(t)$. At the end, the result should be antisymmetric (odd) in $t$. And from this follows my suspicion that the result is actually zero $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The product of DiracDelta[t] with the HeavisideTheta[t] could be reduced as DiracDelta[t]

Comment: @MohamedMostafa No that's not right, HeavisideTheta only shows the right part of the DiracDelta

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your hint, I corrected my answer

Comment: @UlrichNeumann what is the width of DiracDelta to be halved?

Comment: @MohamedMostafa If we assume a "symmetric" DiracDelta[t] it's the part of DiracDelta for t>0

Comment: @UlrichNeumann DiracDelta function is zero for all real numbers except a single point. If this is right then you can't take a "part" of it using HeavisideTheta function.

Comment: Also try taking Laplace transform of both DiracDelta and product of DiracDelta and HeavisideTheta functions you would get the same result.

Comment: Try `FourierTransform` instead and you will see different results!